# Still see errors: php.ini display errors line is being ignored

Tags: php

I added the following line to php.ini `display_errors = On` and errors were being displayed. Now that i'm finished i changed it back to `display_errors = Off` and errors are still showing.

I only added a line and i've tried removing the line and yet errors are still being displayed.

How do i solve this?

Comment: have you restated Apache? after changes in php.ini

Comment: Have you restart your Appache

Comment: have you restart your appache server?

Comment: I'm on shared hosting.. I'm a web designer. i only have access to ftp.

Comment: How did you change php.ini the first time then @user892134 ?

Comment: in that case use ini_set("display_errors", "Off"); at beginning of you file

Comment: May be you are facing issue due to cache. clear your cache and try again.

Comment: where do i put this line? @kamlesh.bar

Comment: @user892134 beginning of file

Comment: I tried clearing my cache and tried using another browser and still showing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to restart the server after doing the edit in `php ini` file & if still its displaying any warinings then try by adding:
`error_reporting(0)` in the common file like header which is loaded on all pages.

If you are using wordpress then add `error_reporting(0)` in `wp_config.php` file just below the line containing `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');`.

Comment: I'm using wordpress, where should i put `error_reporting(0)`?

Comment: In the top of `index.php` in the main wordpress folder.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use phpinfo(); function to figure out what is setting this variable to On.

http://php.net/phpinfo

Comment: any idea what i'll be looking for?

Comment: First of all, Loaded configuration file item should tell you if you are editing the correct configuration file. Then have a look at core section, and search for display_errors item and have a look what local and master values are set to. Master is the value set in the config file, local value is set somewhere in the script. That should help identify the source of this setting.